# How to close a socket file object (makefile) from a different thread?

Tags: python, sockets, stream

I'm using `socket.makefile()` in order to read a textual line-by-line input stream.

I'm also using different threads in order to do that In the background:

```
import threading
import socket
import time

s = socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 9000))
f = s.makefile()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: print(f.readline())).start()
f.close() # This blocks.
```

How can I close the file or socket without blocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may close it like so:

```
# Order is important.
s.close()  # First mark the socket as closed
f.detach().detach().close()  # Mark the file object as closed, and actually close the socket.
```

Internally in CPython, `f.readline()` takes a lock in the underlying `BufferedIO` object. It does so in order to make sure only one thread is reading at a time. The same lock is used for `f.close()` for flushing it's buffers.

If you call `close()` while `readline()` is waiting in the background, your code will wait forever trying to acquire that lock, until the socket will receive a new line.

Unfortunately, attempting to close the socket in the socket level (`s.close()`) is not enough. Closing the socket only marks it as closed, but does not actually close it until all remaining file objects (`makefile`s) are closed as well.

Using `f.detach()` you traverse lower into the IO abstractions (`TextIOWrapper` -> `BufferedIO` -> `SocketIO`), until you reach the `SocketIO` class. Closing the `SocketIO` is what marks the file object as actually closed, and when all are closed, the real socket will be closed and throw an error in the `readline()` thread.

Alternatively, you can directly close the underlying socket file descriptor using `socket.close(s.detach())`.